# How can I force vshost.exe to suppress JIT optimization on module load

Tags: c#, .net, clr, jit, vshost.exe

To step through .Net reference source code you have to:

- disable NGEN (start VS with COMPLUS_ZapDisable=1 environment)
- disable JIT optimization ('Suppress JIT optimization' debugger setting and disable vshost.exe)
- enable source server support

What bothers me is that I have to disable vshost.exe because of [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331.aspx) drawbacks. vshost.exe preloads several assemblies ignoring the 'Suppress JIT optimization' debugger setting. Those assemblies are then optimized causing stepping into them being not an easy task.

Does anybody know how I can force vshost.exe to disable those optimizations while preloading the assemblies?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can tell the JIT to disable optimization for a specific module by creating an appropriate [ini config file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8z24x(v=vs.110).aspx). You only need `COMPLUS_ZapDisable=1` if the module was ngened.

Comment: @BrianReichle: I know about the ini file. But that changes the optimization not only for the current process and takes a lot of effort to add or remove the ini file for every assembly. I don't know how the 'Suppress JIT optimization' debugger setting actually works but it would be great if that option would be recognized by the vshost process.

Comment: If the module is ngened, then the ini file will only have an effect when the use of ngened images is disabled (COMPLUS_ZapDisable), this can provide a limited ability to target a specific process. I think the only remaining option would be to (re-)compile the offending module in debug mode.

Comment: I suspect the 'Suppress JIT optimization' option would cause Visual Studio to call [SetJITCompilerFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233105(v=vs.110).aspx) with CORDEBUG_JIT_DISABLE_OPTIMIZATION in the [LoadModule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231267(v=vs.110).aspx) callback, but this cannot work for NGENed images or after the module has been loaded into the target process.